# How to change Database connection string runtime in Mobile Service TableController API

Tags: database, xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory

I have develop mobile app in xamarin forms and successfully login with Azure B2C. I Create a Web api using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server TableController.
and it works fine.
I want to change database connection string runtime.

for example,

if (UserName == "ABC")

connectionstring = "..."

else if(UserName == "XYZ")

connectionstring = "..."

**How to change Database connection string runtime in Mobile Service  TableController API ?**.

Answer (score 0):

Freinds, I Got the solution.may be it is useful to someone.

In my MobileServiceClient API Startup.Mobile.cs, dbcontext is intialize as below

```
public partial class Startup
{

    public async static void ConfigureMobileApp(IAppBuilder app)

    {
        GlobalVars.ConnectionString = @"Data Source = tcp:stronginventoryapidbserver.database.windows.net, 1433; Initial Catalog = StrongInventoryAPI_db; User ID = strong; Password=Tapsid_het1;";

        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ApplicationContext, StrongInventoryAPI.Migrations.Configuration>());

        app.UseWebApi(config);

    }
}
```

then, i create a ConnectionMstController to change the connection string. Below is Initailize method of Controller.

```
    protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);
        GlobalVars.SID = ((ClaimsPrincipal)User).FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
        if ( GlobalVars.SID.Contains("2e3c2d2a-14e7-4e03-bc5e-b9f6b2b09617"))
            GlobalVars.ConnectionString = @"Data Source = tcp:xxxxxxxxapidbserver.database.windows.net, 1433; Initial Catalog = Drona_db; User ID = strong; Password=xxxxxx;";
        ApplicationContext context = new ApplicationContext(GlobalVars.ConnectionString);
        DomainManager = new EntityDomainManager<ConnectionMst>(context, Request);

    }
```

Remember to add contructor in your context in my case Application Context. my ApplicationConext is,

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    // You can add custom code to this file. Changes will not be overwritten.
    // 
    // If you want Entity Framework to alter your database
    // automatically whenever you change your model schema, please use data migrations.
    // For more information refer to the documentation:
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx
    //private const string connectionStringName = "Name=MyDbConnection";
    public ApplicationContext() : base(GlobalVars.ConnectionString)
    {
    }
    //start
    public ApplicationContext(string ConnectionString)   //connection string change in ConnectionMstController
        : base(ConnectionString)
    {
    }
    //end
    public DbSet<ScheduleMst> ScheduleMsts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AccMst> AccMsts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ConnectionMst> ConnectionMsts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ItemGrpMst> ItemSubGrpMsts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ItemSubGrpMst> ItemSubSubGrpMsts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LotMst> LotMsts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UnitMst> UnitMsts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ItemMst> ItemMsts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SaleOrdMst> SaleOrdMsts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SaleOrdDet> SaleOrdDets { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(
            new AttributeToColumnAnnotationConvention<TableColumnAttribute, string>(
                "ServiceTableColumn", (property, attributes) => attributes.Single().ColumnType.ToString()));
    }
```